# Improve JNA performances without toArray

Tags: java, c, jna

I am trying to create the binding of a C library to my Java code with JNA, but I get very poor performances.

Here is the C header file

```
struct facet_fin_s {
 int facet;
 int fin;
};
typedef struct facet_fin_s facet_fin_t;

struct tab_facet_fin_s {
 facet_fin_s *data;
 int length;
};
typedef struct tab_facet_fin_s tab_facet_fin_t;

struct facet_s{
 int number_of_fins;
 tab_facet_fin_s tab_facet_fin;
};
typedef struct facet_s facet_t;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void getFins(facet_t* const );
```

Here is the C file

```
void getFins(facet_t* const facet)
{
    facet->number_of_fins = 258246;
    facet->tab_facet_fin.length = facet->number_of_fins;
    facet->tab_facet_fin.data = (facet_fin_s*)malloc(sizeof(facet_fin_s) * facet->tab_facet_fin.length);
    memset(facet->tab_facet_fin.data, 0, sizeof(facet_fin_s) * facet->tab_facet_fin.length);

    int loop = 0;
    for (loop=0; loop<facet->tab_facet_fin.length; loop++)
    {
        facet_fin_s fin;
        fin.facet = loop;
        fin.fin = loop;
        facet->tab_facet_fin.data[loop] = fin;
    }
}
```

and finally my test in Java

```
facet_s retFacet = new facet_s();

TestJNABindingLibrary.getFins(retFacet);

Structure facetFin[] = retFacet.tab_facet_fin.data.toArray(retFacet.tab_facet_fin.length);

for (int i = 0; i < facetFin.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(((facet_fin_s)facetFin[i]).fin);
    System.out.println(((facet_fin_s)facetFin[i]).facet);
}
```

The results returned by my function getFins are correct, but the operation is really slow.
I figured that the calling of "toArray" on retFacet.tab_facet_fin.data takes 38 seconds !!

I think JNA spend too much time to synchronize the Java structures with the native struct and copying the data.

I gave a try to the Byte arrays and the ByteBuffer to access the memory directly without copying, but these methods are convenient for primitive objects and not for structs. I also tried to play with pointers to access to the data easily, but without any success.

My goal is to find a way to improve the performances and still keep the java code clear and easy to manipulate (I will have a lot of these functions in the project). Is there any way to achieve that with JNA ? (I have already considered JNI, SWIG and BridJ..). Some code is welcome ;-)

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is my try at disabling the auto-synch and reading the field

```
facet_s retFacet = new facet_s();
retFacet.setAutoSynch(false);
TestJNABindingLibrary.getFins(retFacet);
facet_fin_s[] fins = (facet_fin_s[])retFacet.tab_facet_fin.readField("data");
```

unfortunately, `fins` appears to be `null`

**EDIT 2**

Technomage told me that I have to read `tab_facet_fin` first. But I still can't get the results as an array.

```
tab_facet_fin_s tab = (tab_facet_fin_s)retFacet.readField("tab_facet_fin");
facet_fin_s[] fins = (facet_fin_s[])tab.readField("data");
```

raises a cast exception. Is there any easy way to read this field ?

**EDIT 3**

Thanks to Technomage, I gave a complete try at the `readField` strategy. There are two ways of getting the data, depending if `data` is a `Pointer` or a `Structure.ByReference`.

here is the common part (each java class calls `setAutoSynch(false)` in its constructor)

```
facet_s retFacet = new facet_s();
TestJNABindingLibrary.getFins(retFacet);
```

then the `Pointer` case

```
int length = (int)retFacet.readField("number_of_fins");
tab_facet_fin_s tab = (tab_facet_fin_s)retFacet.readField("tab_facet_fin");
int[] data = new int[length*2];
tab.data.read(0, data, 0, data.length);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(data[i]);
}
```

or the `Structure.ByReference` case.

```
tab_facet_fin_s tab = (tab_facet_fin_s)retFacet.readField("tab_facet_fin");
facet_fin_s s = (facet_fin_s)tab.readField("data");
facet_fin_s[] data = (facet_fin_s[])s.toArray(length);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println(data[i].fin);
   System.out.println(data[i].facet);
}
```

Now my opinion :

- The `readField` strategy might be a good way to optimize the performances and avoid useless copy. This might be a good trick, but not relevant here because my struct have only data that I want to read. If my other structs in my project contain data that I don't want to read, then I will use it definitively.
- The Pointer case : Unfortunately, JNAerator does automatically generate my `data` as `Structure.ByReference` and not `Pointer`. But let's imagine I get these `Pointer`. Then I can as well access to the int values inside data really fast. If I'm not wrong, this way is exactly the same as calling `Pointer.getIntArray`. I see 2 problems here. First, I completely loose the benefit of having a `facet_fin_s`class in Java. The way of parsing the data are OK, but not really convenient. Secondly, if my struct `facet_fin_s` possess other type of members (and this is the case for some structs of the library I am trying to bind), then this strategy is irrelevent.
- The Structure.ByReference case : The good point here is that we get the data as an array of `facet_fin_s`. This is a good point for the code readability. Unfortunately, we are back at the first problematic beacause we have here to use this damned `Structure.toArray` to access the data. This function create copy of memory from Native memory to Java memory. For big amount of data, this function is really slow.

Is there really any way to read the native memory data in a very fast way and keep the original "architecture", without completely rewritting Java or C code ?

- Keep using the java classes representing the C structs
- Avoid as much as possible the rewritting of a lot of tools or classes in Java or C so that we can use JNAerator only
- Fast and readable access to native memory, or fast copy from native memory to java memory

I think I am facing the limitations of JNA...

Comment: Sounds like a job for [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/). Let me know if you need to know something in specific, and I will answer below!

Comment: Hi Samuel. I already spend some time on your JavaCPP project few days ago. The problem is that I have a big C library to bind with many functions and structs and I cannot afford time to write all the wrapping requested by JavaCPP. Moreover, the C library will continue to improve. So I was more looking for a solution which could generate the binding for me (like JNAerator). If JavaCPP can provide such functionnality, then let me know. I will give it a try.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on that right now. I'll be releasing some preliminary code "soon" that works with most C header files. Although it's going to take some time to get this working well for every case, I think it has good chances to succeed where others have failed. Please subscribe to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/javacpp-project) if you'd like to receive news about that :)

Comment: Ta-dah, and here is the result: [JavaCPP Presets](https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/source/browse?repo=presets). All the convenience of JNAerator without the performance penalties :)

Answer (score 2):

You should turn off auto-synch of structure memory ([`Structure.setAutoSynch(false)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#setAutoRead%28boolean%29)).  Then you can call [`Structure.readField(String)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#readField%28java.lang.String%29) only as needed to access the fields of interest.

`Structure.toArray()` doesn't by itself consume that much time, but synching native memory to Java fields for a large number of structures ends up causing a lot of reflection, which is generally slow.  This will depend on the number of structures involved and the number of fields in each (and recursively nested structure references add more overhead).

BTW, you can cast the results of `Structure.toArray()` directly to `facet_fin_s[]` so you don't have to repeat the casts later.

If you've only got a few fields in the many structs, and need to access all of them, you'll be better off with a block representation of memory (NIO or primitive array) that has better Java to native transfer performance.  You really don't want to be transferring thousands of fields individually no matter what the platform for doing so.  Ideally you'll want to pull all of the data to be transferred into a single buffer or array and perform the transfer once (`Pointer.getIntArray()` might serve for this particular case).

**EDIT**

Assuming your `data` field within `tab_facet_fin` is of type `Pointer`, then you can extract your data like this:

```
int[] buf = new int[LENGTH*2];
tab_facet_fin.data.read(0, buf, 0, buf.length);
```

If instead you map `data` as `Structure.ByReference` (i.e. `struct*`), then you'd need to do the following:

```
facet_fin_s s = (facet_fin_s)tab.readField("data");
facet_fin_s[] data = (facet_fin_s[])s.toArray(LENGTH);
```

Note that you should set auto sync false in the ctor of all structures where you want to avoid it so that it happens automatically when the structure is created.  `Structure.toArray()` calls `Structure.autoRead()` on all array elements before returning.

**EDIT 2**

In general, the JVM is not kind towards native accesses of any sort; there is a large overhead for making a single native function call.  The real overhead of `Structure.toArray()` is reading each field one by one, each read of which results in a JNI crossing.  The best solution is to make as few JNI transitions as possible, so this means transferring the data and *then* sorting it out into its component parts.

If you pull everything over in a single buffer, you can still use the information calculated by JNA to access it.  You could conceivably make your own `Memory` class backed by native memory, but optimized to read the entire native memory chunk once and then override all the `Pointer.getXXX` methods to access a Java-side buffer instead of native memory.  This might be a useful feature in JNA, and could conceivably be the default optimization.  The drawback would be that you now have twice the memory usage, so it's not necessarily always the best solution.

NOTE: it is trivial to extend the interfaces generated by JNAerator to add mappings that it wasn't configured to generate.  For instance, if it emits the following:

```
interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    void myFunction(Pointer arg);
}
```

You can augment it like this:

```
interface MyLibrary2 extends MyLibrary {
    void myFunction(MyStructure arg);
}
```

Comment: Hi technomage. I have already tried the auto-synch trick but I couldn't get it work. See my edit on the original post

Comment: As for the `Pointer.getIntArray()`, I have also already tested it. The performances are great (exactly what I want) but I want to bind a library (for which I don't have the source code) that uses structs containing many fields (primitives and structs). I could indeed extract just the data required thanks to a custom function in C and then transfer them with NIO or primitive array, but since these data are topological and geometrical data, I would like to avoid messing up the "architecture" of these structures

Comment: You'll need to read the `tab_facet_fin` field before you'll be able to read *its* fields.

Comment: OK, I did it, but I still don't see how I will finally be able to read the data as an array. Casting doesn't work (see my Edit2). I still don't know if I can avoid the "toArray"...

Comment: Hi Technomage. Thanks for your help so far. I added my thoughts about your solutions in the Edit 3 (see above)